# Retrieving greek characters from a sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, unicode, utf-8

I am having problems with retrieving greek letters from a sqlite database.  The letters are in my sqlite database and I am able to get the letters from my user.  Here is my code:

```
NSString *selectedChapter = [SecondViewController chapterToSearch];
```

(a few lines later)

```
 const char *sqlStatement=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM samples WHERE chapter IN ('%@')",selectedChapter]UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &selectStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));   
            }
            while (sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSString *chapterLetter  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement,0)];
}
```

It skips over the 'while' statement.  Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be     `while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {`

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.  The computer reads the "while" statement, but does not pick up the lines in between the { }.

Comment: your while is stepping in selectStatement in place of sqlStatement

Comment: Thank you but that is not the problem.  It reads the sqlite database just fine when I put a "non-greek letter" statement in the sqlStatement.  Thanks anyway.